# I need to convert a json file to html using python

Tags: python, html, json

```
import json
from json2html import *
with open('/Users/arnav/downloads/random-report.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    e = json2html.convert(json=d)
    g = ("/Users/arnav/downloads/random-report.html")
    with open(g, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(e))
        print("yes") #to see if the code worked
```

This is my code so far, whenever I run this, it prints yes but the file stays the same, any idea why?

Comment: this code works fine for me, are you sure that `random-report.json` has valid content?

Comment: It does have valid content, the strange thing is my code isn't running anymore, somebody earlier suggested that it was because of     from json2html import *    and    e = json2html.convert(json=d)    but I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: if your code is not running it probably has another reason, this code that you shared is fine, I copied and pasted it and it runs ok, so you have to check the files(both json and html) , maybe check your IDE , and to make sure you can add `file.close()` at the end(after writing on file )

Comment: Thank you, just fixed my problem and now it is working